# Vue js with debug package

Tags: javascript, debugging, vue.js

I'm trying use [debug package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) in my Vue project.
I have done some steps but didn't work:

- installed package : `npm install debug`
- set debug module in vue component:

```
<script>
import debug from 'debug'

const log = debug('app:logging')

export default {
...
  created(){
    log('testing logging');
  }
...
}
<script>
```

- did run the project in VS Code powershell: `$env:DEBUG='app:*'; npm run serve`
- did try cmder with `set DEBUG=app:* & npm run serve`
- did try set DEBUG in .env file got message `[dotenv][DEBUG] "DEBUG" is already defined in "process.env" and will not be overwritten`

What should I do to get this working corectly? I would like to see the message `testing logging` in console.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the [documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#output-streams):

> ```
> var log = debug('app:log');
> // set this namespace to log via console.log
> log.log = console.log.bind(console); // don't forget to bind to console!
> log('goes to stdout');
> ```

Comment: Still I don't see the message :(. Shouldn't I see the stderr on console too?